# AreaSeries only shows hovered

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.11

I need mouse move event in my chart(QChart) drawn using AreaSeries.In AreaSeries , it shows only 'hovered' event. How can i get a mouse move event in AreaSeries??

```cpp
connect(sectorplain->areaseries,&AreaSeries::hovered,this&MainWindow::testfunction);
```

I need 'mousemove' event instead of 'hovered' in AreaSeries..